# How to automatically press right arrow key in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run this command

```
elinks /www/test.html | (then automatically press the right arrow key)
```

After opening the `test.html` with `elinks` I want it to automatically press the righ arrow key. Is that possible ? What command should I use to do that?

Comment: @dev0, xdotool requires X server

Comment: I'm on openwrt and xdotool is not supported

Comment: @Squidward, is uinput driver loaded, ie, do you have /dev/uinput or /dev/input/uinput device? If not, try `insmod uinput` or `modprobe uinput` and see if they show up

Comment: `insmod uinput` gives me `Failed to find uinput. Maybe it is a built in module ?` and `modprobe uinput` gives me `kmod: failed to find a module named uinput`

Comment: @Squidward, do you have /dev/uinput device? Or /dev/input/uinput?

Comment: Have you looked at elinks scripting options? http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html#lua-scripting

Comment: solved guys, check out the answer section

Answer (score 0):

The VT100 right arrow key escape sequence is `'\EOC'`, perhaps you could use that?

Comment: `elinks /www/test.html | \EOC` gives me `-ash: EOC: not found`

Comment: @Squidward, you can't pipe the output of `elinks` to that. Perhaps the `expect` command in conjunction with `printf \EOC` will give you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
elinks -auto-submit 1 /www/test.html
```

Comment: Always check `man yourCommand` and `yourCommand --help` BEFORE asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

user does not understand what a pipe does.

`command1 | command2` sends the output of command1 towards input of command2. Not the reverse.

So to send the escape code to elinks:

```
printf '\E0C' | elinks /www/test.html
```